# muZ returns different answers with datalog and pdr engines

Tags: z3py

I am running muZ over python with version 4.40.
For one query I get a different result when I set

```
fp.set( "engine", "datalog" )
```

And when I set

```
fp.set( "engine", "pdr" )
```

The program below returns unsat for both queries with datalog and sat with pdr

```
sortTest, lList = EnumSort( "TestSort", ["1","2","3","4"] )
fp = Fixedpoint()
fp.set( "engine", "datalog" )
funcRel = Function( "TestFunc", sortTest, BoolSort() )
fp.register_relation( funcRel )
fp.fact( funcRel( lList[ 0 ] ) )
fp.rule( funcRel( lList[ 1 ] ), funcRel( lList[ 0 ] ) )
fp.rule( funcRel( lList[ 2 ] ), funcRel( lList[ 1 ] ) )
print fp.query( funcRel( lList[ 1 ] ) )
print fp.query( funcRel( lList[ 2 ] ) )
```

When I remove the line that defines the seconed rule, namely:
    fp.rule( funcRel( lList[ 2 ] ), funcRel( lList[ 1 ] ) )
then the first query returns sat also with datalog

An update: everything seems to work when I replace enum sort with bit vectors.
Could you please confirm that this is the problem?

Comment: Please improve formatting. Format all inline code and citations. Here's a manual for you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: If there's an error or exception, post the stacktrace in your answer. It really helps understand the problem.

Comment: And the header needs to be more exact. Like "Error X when running Y in Z".